# Split a Camel Route according to type

Tags: split, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I have an Apache Camel exchange that, as result of some processing, contains a `Pair<List<Message>`, `List<Error>>`. I want to split my Camel route into two paths, one only processing the `Message`s, and one only processing the `Error`s. Using a pseudo-DSL, I am looking for something like this:

```kotlin
split(MyPairSplitter::Class)
  .to("direct:process-messages")
  .to("direct:process-errors")
```

Now, this is not how the *splitter* EIP works. To my understanding, the splitter creates a sequence of exchanges that all have the same data type as body and that are all fed into a single route; but I would like to have two routes that process *different* data types. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Splitter doesn't really care what the type of the thing being split is. I think what you're looking for is the [Composed Message Processor pattern](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/composed-message-processor.html).

```
split(body())
    .when(simple("${body.class.name == 'Message'"))
        .to("direct:process-messages")
    .otherwise()   
        .to("direct:process-errors")
    .end()
.end()
```